# Question regarding inheritance in wxWidgets

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor, wxwidgets

Currently I'm attempting to write my own wxObject, and I would like for the class to be based off of the wxTextCtrl class.

Currently this is what I have:

```
class CommandTextCtrl : public wxTextCtrl {
    public:
        void OnKey(wxKeyEvent& event);
    private:
        DECLARE_EVENT_TABLE()
};
```

Then later on I have this line of code, which is doesn't like:

```
CommandTextCtrl *ctrl = new CommandTextCtrl(panel, wxID_ANY, *placeholder, *origin, *size);
```

...and when I attempt to compile the program I receive this error:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘CommandTextCtrl::CommandTextCtrl(wxPanel*&, <anonymous enum>, const wxString&, const wxPoint&, const wxSize&)’
```

It seems that it doesn't inherit the constructor method with wxTextCtrl.  Does anyone happen to know why it doesn't inherit the constructor?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C++ does **not** inherit constructors (you may be thinking of Python, which *does*;-).  A class w/o explicitly declared ctors, like your `CommandTextCtrl`, in C++, only has default and copy ctors supplied implicitly by C++ rules.

So, you need to explicitly define a ctor with your desired signature, which basically "bounces back" to the base class's -- with the `CommandTextCtrl(...): wxTextCtrl(...) {}` kind of syntax, of course.

Comment: Ah!  Thank you!  I'm somewhat new to C++ (I'm migrating over from Java and Python).

Comment: @celestialorb, you're welcome -- I'm a C++ expert who's mostly been using Python for the last several years, myself (wish I knew Java's details as deeply as I do C++'s and Python's, but I just don't have enough real-world experience in it... I _think_ Java, like C++, doesn't inherit constructors, but, I wouldn't bet my shirt on it;-).